# Get username by id using identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity

I have asp.net core Identity and I want if it is possible to retrieve username of any user using the identity. I know we can subtract Id from the current user as (this is only for current Jwt token):

```
User.Identity.GetFirstClaimValueByType("id")
```

I read other questions and someone suggests to use

```
string username = HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(ID).UserName;
```

So I try to use HttpContextAccessor but does not have extension method for `GetOwinContext`, how can I access it.

Try:

But now I want to send id to get a username is that possible? Regards

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext
```

Comment: Are you working within a Controller? If so, you can inject the ApplicationUserManager directly into the Controller's constructor & call the FindById() method.

Comment: Yes, I'm working with the controller, but what's that dependency injection? I try as '`private read-only IApplicationUser _applicationUser;` but I can't found reference @MattHensley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use the `ApplicationUserManager` inside of your controller.

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private static ApplicationUserManager _userManager;


    public MyController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }


    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

        var userName = user.UserName;
    }
}
```

Please note: The type of `ApplicationUserManager` must be the same type of `UserManager<TUser>` registered by the Startup.cs for your Identity classes.

Comment: When I try to use `ApplicationUserManager` it suggests me to install `Fluent.Infrastructure` package, what is the library of that ApplicationUserManager?

Comment: Here is an article outlining out to get started with Microsoft Identity. You shouldn't need to install any non-Microsoft NuGet packages.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio